# How to show a gif before setting visiblity false in Java?

Tags: java, wait, gif, intersect

Alright, so I'm currently coding a Space Invaders knock off. Basically, when the enemy is hit with a missile (already coded and works, but can post if absolutely necessary) I want it to play an explosion animation then set the visibility of it to false, which will also remove it from the frame. I can't figure out how to do both, I can rather play the gif then it gets stuck on the last frame without ever disappearing or or just instantly removes it and skips the gif.

Here's what I have for my Board class (the panel)

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
        Enemy e = (Enemy)enemies.get(i);
        if(e.isVisible())
        g2d.drawImage(e.getImage(), e.getX(),e.getY(), 45,45, this);
    }
    if(friendly.isVisible()){
        g2d.drawImage(friendly.getImage(), friendly.getX(), friendly.getY(), 40, 40, this);
    }
}



if (r3.intersects(r4)){ //Missile Hitting Enemy
    m.setVisible(false);
    bullets++;
    Bullets.setText("Bullets: " + bullets);
    e.explode();

    if(Enemy.called){
        e.setVisible(false);
        enemies.remove(j);
    }
    Resources.enemyHit.play();
    Score++;
    score.setText("Score: " + Score );
}
```

and my Enemy class methods:

```
private boolean visible = true;
private Image image;
public static boolean called = false;

public void explode(){
    Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit (); //Code for Created Several Instances of a GIF
    image = t.createImage(this.getClass().getResource(explosionGif));
    called = true;
}

public void setVisible (boolean visible){
    this.visible = visible;
}
```